# How to print only checked(checkbox) records in Grid

Tags: javascript

I am totally confused how to print only selected records, my issue is that when I check some checkboxes as mentioned in the screenshot it not only prints the checked records it prints all records in the grid.
Here is screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/3btDXoAayK
In the screenshot I selected only few records not all but when I click on print it shows all records in print document.
Please send me code to fix this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is working please

```
let grid: Grid = new Grid( 
{ 
    dataSource: inventoryData, 
    allowPaging: true, 
    load: load, 
    allowSelection: true, 
    . . . . . . 
}); 
grid.appendTo('#Grid'); 

function load(){ 
this.on('printGrid-Init', function (args) { args.printgrid.dataSource = this.getSelectedRecords(); }); 
}
```